# Large voltage drop across source terminal

Tags: mosfet, voltage

I am using an N-channel MOSFET to enable another IC.

My gate voltage=1V, the drain voltage=3.3V.

After rigging up the circuit, the voltage across EN_DC23 was measured with reference to ground and it was 0.7V

Can someone help me in finding out the reason for this large voltage drop?

I am using a Diodes Incorporated ZXM61N02FTA MOSFET.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "across soruce terminal", you have a voltage difference between two nodes and it's not clear what nodes you're refering to.

Comment: When i measure the voltage at source pin it was 0.7V. What is the reason for such large voltage drop at source pin. With reference to my circuit, the measured voltage at EN_DC23 is 0.7V @po.pe

Comment: What is the reference? Ground? Where is `EN_DC23` connected to?

Comment: The reference is ground. EN_DC23 is connected to enable pin of regulator.

Comment: @Shifali  Please post your comments in the question.   As in clarify *The measured voltage is 0.7V.*!

Comment: Hope its understandable now

Answer (score 4):

The circuit you have built is called a [source follower.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_drain) It is also known as a common drain amplifier.

In a source follower, the source voltage can never rise higher than the gate voltage.  The source will **always** be lower than the gate voltage.

You have a gate voltage of 1V above ground.  The source can never be higher than 1V above ground.

You also have a series resistor between the drain and the 3.3V rail.  That reduces the current that can flow through the MOSFET.

The MOSFET source should be at 1V, but with the 1k resistor in series and the load of the "ENABLE" pin, the source voltage drops a bit to just 0.7V.

The simplest solution is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMaygO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- R3 holds the gate of the MOSFET high, keeping EN_DC23 low.
- A high (1V) on VCCINT causes Q1 to conduct, pulling the gate of M1 low and allowing EN-DC23 to be pulled up by R1.

Whatever EN_DC3 is, it might already have a pull up.  Then you could remove R1.

Comment: What's the need of Q1, why not connect the gate directly to VCCINT, is it because VCCINT is not high enough to switch on MOSFET ?

Comment: @MeenieLeis:  Right.  VCCINT can't fully turn on M1 - that 1V is too low.  R3 can pull the gate up to 3.3V, which is high enough for M1 to "switch on."

Answer (score 0):

Vs=0.7V with Vg=1V means Vgs=0.3 V with is near or below the threshold Vgs(th) for this logic level switch.

This is **not** how you make a non-inverting “high-side” switch.

If you require Vs=3.3V with Vg=1V for a high side switch to Vdd=3.3V, then please  define all your interface design specs with tolerances for voltage, current and temperature in all states.

Comment: VG=1V, VD=3.3V. The enable pin has a VIH=1.4V and VIL=0.4V. Hence i want source to be greater than 1.4V for enable pin of IC to not be in undetermined state. Enable pin requires sink current of 0.1uA. Temperature is 30C

Comment: yes But put this in your question as if you were writing a design spec.

Comment: Then what do you mean by ''please define all your interface design spec''

Comment: Every transistor and logic chip IC has at least a page of interface specs with conditions and tolerances. You have none.  See the difference? That's how pro's design something.  At least define Logic level inputs and output V,I ...in all states